# Finding Max of an array using Recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

So it's pretty simple to find the max of an array using a for loop or a while loop, but I wanted to try it out with recursion. For some reason, the substring doesn't work - it says "cannot find symbol". Why is this? My strategy is continue subdividing and comparing the two sides until there is only one left which should be the max....am I doing it right? Thanks

```
   public static int max(int[] array) {

    if (array.length == 1) {
        return array[0];
    } else {
        int mid = (array.length) / 2;
        int leftmax = max(array.substring(0, mid));
        int rightmax = max(array.substring(mid, array.length));
        if (leftmax > rightmax) {
            return leftmax;
        } else {
            return rightmax;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what programming language is this? Java? JavaScript?

Comment: Why recursion? You might blow your stack.

Comment: I need to practice my recursion :o

Comment: If you wait few minutes, I will add answer with explained recursion which works. I hope you will learn from it, right now, you are not using recursion at all :).

Comment: `substring` is a method on a `String`. Also, it is probably better to pass in high and low indexes to search for instead of trying to copy the array every iteration.

Comment: @libik why do you say he is not using recursion? he is calling `max()` from within `max()`. That is recursion.

Comment: @clcto - aah, true, I am blind :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `array` is of type `int[]` not `String`, you cannot use `substring()`. Instead, keep track of which indexes you are searching through. Copying the array each iteration is a waste of both space and time.

```
int max( int[] array ){ return max( array, 0, array.length - 1 ); }

int max( int[] array, int low, int high )
{
    if (low == high) {
        return array[low];
    } 
    else {
        int mid = (high + low) / 2;
        int leftmax = max(array, low, mid );
        int rightmax = max(array, mid, high );
        if (leftmax > rightmax) {
            return leftmax;
        } 
        else {
            return rightmax;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are going to want to use `Arrays.copyOfRange`. `Substring` isn't going to work on an array.

```
int[] firstHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(original, 0, original.length/2);
int[] secondHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(original, original.length/2, original.length);
```

I can't comment on your algorithm.